# Browse and Get the remote file from FTP Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, ftp

I need to browse and get some files from remote server and download to the local server in Drupal 7.  Can anyone know how to do it?  Is there any module can be used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your file type, you can try [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources/) module.
If you are wondering why I said "depending on field type", that's because FileFields are only available for entities. For site logo and other custom file fields, you have to integrate is manually.

**But currently it cannot browse a remote server via FTP.
You can browser self server or remote server via cURL.**